# Force links to open in ORIGINAL window wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hyperlink

I have a WordPress niche website with lots of posts that ALL of the links in the posts (internal+external) are hard-coded to open in new window (`target=_blank`) . I decided I want to change this so only external links will open in new window, and internal links will open in the same original window (automatically, by script, not hard-coded).

I installed a plugin that does that automatically (this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/open-external-links-in-a-new-window/).

It works great for new posts, but I also want all the previous posts' internal links to open in the same window (they still open in new window because of the hard coded `target=_blank`.)

I followed the instructions on this post: http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2016/01/dont-open-internal-links-in-new-window.html. That didn't work (I also deactivated the former plugin above. Didn't work).

Other than that post, I didn't find any other post online talking about this topic.

**To make it clear: my final result needs to be:** all links in posts, including previous hard-coded `target=_blank` links, open external links in new window and internal link in same window.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution- I added this before the `</head>`:

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("a[target='_blank']").removeAttr("target");
});
</script>
```

This removes 'target=_blank' to all links in webpage. I left the plugin I installed earlier activated, and both seems to work well together.

Hope this helps to whoever needs this.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin **"External Links – nofollow, noopener & new window"** manages external and internal links without waiting for the page to render.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-external-links/